# Get rid of the Courier font

Tags: windows, fonts

I just want to get rid of Courier/Courier New on my system. It looks just horrible. I tried to replace it with `FontSubstitutes` key in the registry.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]`

`"Courier New CE,0"="Consolas"`

`"Courier New CE,238"="Consolas"`

`"Courier,0"="Consolas"`

This didn't help. After reboot applications still use Courier/Courier New font.

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out. You need to set `"Courier New"="Consolas"` and `"Courier"="Consolas"`. Don't even touch keys mentioned above.

Comment: Calling people names like that is completely unacceptable here on Stack Overflow. You were probably downvoted because your question is Off-Topic here. Downvoted again and migrated to Superuser.com.

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, you shouldn’t.

This font is needed by Windows and applications. It is protected for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

Try use [Mactype](http://code.google.com/p/mactype/), it simplifies all the manually settings for you.